# Who moderates the moderators? These guys!

Tags: discussion, moderation

First off, thanks to everyone who participated at the [unofficial pro-tem moderator nominations](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/who-should-be-the-moderators-moderators) meta post!

Throughout the beta, we need members from this site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us ensure that this community’s issues are properly addressed:

[Andy http://moderators.stackexchange.com/users/flair/78.png](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/users/78/)
[Annonomus Penguin http://moderators.stackexchange.com/users/flair/42.png](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/users/42/annonomus-person)
[AJ Henderson http://moderators.stackexchange.com/users/flair/11.png](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11/aj-henderson)

I may eventually be contacting additional users to fill more moderator slots, but I wanted to get initial mods activated before we got too far into the public beta.

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Yes, almost certainly. At the nomination post alone, there were more great choices than positions available. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My inability to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections several weeks after graduation.**

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: Title should be changed to "Who are the moderators of Community Building" or similar.

Comment: Yeah, but that's boring. Note to future readers: the title here made more sense based on the original name of this site: "Moderators Stack Exchange." (What? I'm _funny_, dangit.)